# Our own camera interface in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I try to make app with my own Camera interface. I use android.hardware.Camera. First time I did step by step [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#basics) tutorial, but some problem (in surfaceCreated ) `NullPointerException` so I have tried this but something is wrong.

```
public class AktivitaDisplej extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera aKamera=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SurfaceView surface=new SurfaceView(this);
        surface.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        surface.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        setContentView(surface);

    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


        try {
            aKamera=Camera.open();
            aKamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        Camera.Parameters param=aKamera.getParameters();
        param.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        aKamera.setParameters(param);
        aKamera.startPreview();
    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        aKamera.stopPreview();
        aKamera.release();
        aKamera=null;
    }
}
```

ERRORS:

```
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:350)
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:327)
08-27 21:00:52.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5093):     at sal.camera.AktivitaDisplej.surfaceCreated(AktivitaDisplej.java:55)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: did you add permission in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: I have spent 3 hours because of my stupidity. Thank you